# C# fields: mandatory initialization but still accessible to deserializer

Tags: c#, deserialization, c#-10.0

I'm facing a dilemma that's very common in C# (and other OO languages) where I'm trying to meet 3 competing requirements :

> 1. I absolutely don't want the end-user of my class to **forget** to initialize some of the fields, at construction time.
> 2. I want a deserializer to be able to instantiate that class and **populate the fields** without silently being "blocked" by a private setter.
> 3. I don't want any **non-initialized fields** left hanging (e.g. a list has to be constructed, no loose `null` in there!)

**Note:**

> **This is NOT the same question as this old one :** [How to make a property required in c#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10794346/how-to-make-a-property-required-in-c)
> for two reasons :
>
> 1. It doesn't deal with requirement #2 (expose fields for deserialization)
> 2. It's 10 years old, and C# has evolved a lot since then.

So, let's say that this is my class :

```
public class MyClass {
     public bool Field1 {get; set;}
     public IEnumerable<bool> Field2 {get; set;} = default!; 
}
```

*Note : don't obsess over the `= default!` bit, here I'm just making the compiler happy (it detects non-initialized fields) to move on to the core of the issue.*

if I needed to meet **requirement #1 only** then I would **NOT** do this :

```
var o = new MyClass() {
             Field1 = true
             // Uh oh, I forgot Field2
        };
```

Instead I would do this :

```
public class MyClass {
     public bool Field1 {get; private set;}
     public IEnumerable<bool> Field2 {get; private set;}

     public MyClass(bool field1, IEnumerable<bool> field2) {
         Field1 = field1;
         Field2 = field2;
     } 
}
```

For **requirement #3 only** I would do this :

```
public class MyClass {
     public bool Field1 {get; private set;}
     public IEnumerable<bool> Field2 {get; private set;} = new List<bool>();

     public MyClass(bool field1) {
         Field1 = field1;
     } 
}

// ...

c.Field2.AddRange(...);
```

I would **NOT** do this because despite protecting the fields from tampering, it **does not guarantee requirement #1 :**

```
public class MyClass {
     public bool Field1 {get; init;}
     public IEnumerable<bool> Field2 {get; init;} = new List<bool>();
}
```

But now I have to fullfil **requirement #2** . That's a problem because the deserializer cannot populate `protected` or `private` fields.

Which means that this would **NOT** work, as `Field1` would remain `false` :
(note: we're assuming that the deserializer is properly configured : no upper-case/lower-case nonsense or whatnot)

```
string json = @"{ ""Field1"": true, ""Field2"": [] }";
var o = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<MyClass>(json);
Assert(o.Field1 == true); // fails
```

The only solution I'm aware of to fulfill **all 3 requirements** is a constructor that has ALL the fields :

```
public class MyClass {
     public bool Field1 {get; private set;}
     public IEnumerable<bool> Field2 {get; private set;} = new List<bool>();

     [JsonConstructor] // <-- to make it air-tight!
     public MyClass(bool field1, IEnumerable<bool> field2) {
         Field1 = field1;
         Field2 = field2;
     } 
}

string json = @"{ ""Field1"": true, ""Field2"": [] }";
var o = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<MyClass>(json);
Assert(o.Field1 == true); // succeeds
```

even that solution is not perfect, because if I add a field "Field3" to the class then I might forget to add it to the exhaustive constructor, and the deserialization would silently ignore it. Fail!

**My question :**

**Is there an elegant way of achieving this in modern C#?**
Many answers about this topic are 10+ years old. C# has made a ton of progress in every direction since then.
Ideally, I'd like an answer for **.Net6 (C# 10)** AND possibly an answer for more recent C# (C# 11+)

Comment: Look at the [`required` modifier](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/required). You can also fulfill all of your requirements with a record: `public record MyClass(bool Field1, IEnumerable<bool> Field2)`.

Comment: The duplicate does answer all your questions. Even though the question might be 10 years old, if you scroll down, you'll read more answers mentioning `init` and `required` and records. See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62270834/use-system-text-json-to-deserialize-properties-with-private-setters.

Comment: @CodeCaster the word "deserialization" does not appear anywhere, therefore that aspect of the issue is not discussed nor indexed, therefore it's not searchable. I will not say more, thank you for your dedication.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For C# 11 - there is feature introduced to specifically support such scenarios - [`required` modifier](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/required) which allows your to do something like (also note the usage of [`init` keyword](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/init) which declares an init-only setter which allows to assign a value to the property only during object construction):

```cs
public class MyClass 
{
     public required bool Field1 {get; init;}
     public required IEnumerable<bool> Field2 {get; init;}
}
```

The last option can also be reduced to using [`record`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/builtin-types/record)s (available since C# 9):

```cs
public record MyClass(bool Field1, IEnumerable<bool> Field2);
```

P.S.

Note that `required` modifier [is also considered by `System.Text.Json`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/system-text-json/required-properties), so marking property with it will make the corresponding JSON property required in the JSON payload.

Comment: I like your enthusiasm and prolificacy in posting answers, but please search for duplicates first. There's enough knowledge spread out over multiple Q&As already.

Comment: @CodeCaster see my explanation of why this is not really a duplicate.